# Make a php a href link with variable clickable

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a question.
I have this code to get an profile name as an link.

```
    <a href=<?php echo $userpro->permalink( get_the_author_meta('ID') );
?>><?php echo $user_id=get_the_author_meta('display_name');?></a>
```

The link isnt clickable. I am a newbie in coding.
So maybe somebody can help me :)

Greetings

Comment: What does the HTML look like that being produced by this?

Comment: If you can't click on the link, then the you need to diagnose the problem with the code the browser gets. Even if the problem is because of the PHP, you need to look at the HTML (and maybe CSS and JS) to find out what you need to change.

Comment: Seems you forgot to include the quote? I guess...

Comment: `href="<?php echo $userpro->permalink( get_the_author_meta('ID') );?>"`

Comment: i wrote this in php file. @void main
dont work

Comment: Ok if i write in my CSS file the layout is broken but the link work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $userpro->permalink(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>">
    <?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name'); ?>
</a>
```

If it doesnt work... please supply the value and initialisation of $userpro!